# Magento 2.3: Custom Customer Attributes are not getting saved

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, customer

We are using **Magento 2 Enterprise Edition** and created some of the custom customer attributes via admin panel (it's one of the feature in enterprise edition though it's not available in community edition).

I can see all the new custom attributes in frontend. However, when I fill in the data and try to save, it's not getting saving but when I do the same process that is saving the data via the admin panel, it's saving without any issues.

So why am I not able to save the data from the frontend?

Any help will be appreciated!

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customergroupid = '';
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customergroupid = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();    
}
?>
<?php if(($customergroupid == x) || ($customergroupid == y)): ?>
<?php if ($block->hasUserDefinedAttributes()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->isShowContainer()): ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php foreach ($block->getUserDefinedAttributes() as $attribute):?> 
        <?php $attributeContent = $block->getAttributeHtml($attribute);?>
        <?php if ($attributeContent): ?>
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $attributeContent ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php if ($block->isShowContainer()): ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: How you create custom attribute?

Comment: In enterprise edition, we have an option to create customer attributes which is not available in community edition. Pleased see the screenshot in question

Comment: I am asking the value which you field during creation of the attibute.

Comment: I have created an attribute called Marital Status and selected the option Yes for show on frontend. But still its not displaying.

Comment: But I can see that attribute in backend

Comment: Can you please add steps to reproduct issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EE provides two set of attributes.

**Customer** and **Customer Address Attributes** attributes.

As per question, it looks like you have created `Martial status` attribute typed `drop-down` on the **Customer** section.

> I can see all the new custom attributes in frontend. However, when I
>   fill in the data and try to save, its not getting saving but when I do
>   the same process that is saving the data via admin panel, its saving
>   without any issues.

If you are facing an issue(fill in the data) while Registration or Edit account page, there may be something custom code breaking on customer_save related events.

As i have checked the `boolean`, `drop-down` and `text field` type attributes works very well and reflected in the Admin as well as Front-end section.

- **Used in forms should be selected as all the options**

Custom and Customer address attributes are native feature, even you don't have to put any template whether in the admin address template or customer related templates files.

Only needs to create the attribute from the Magento admin.

**EDIT:2** FOR CUSTOMER GROUP ID

Copy file `vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/view/frontend/templates/form/userattributes.phtml` and paste into the theme folder.

So file location would be follows:
`app/design/frontend/Namespace/Themename/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/templates/customer/form/userattributes.phtml`

Above file will be using the class -

`$block` `\Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Block\Form` and

`$block` `\Magento\CustomAttributeManagement\Block\Form`

**FILE: userattributes.phtml**

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customergroupid = '';
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
     $customergroupid = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();    
}

$allowedAttributes = array('allowed_for_retailer','maritial_status');
?>

<?php foreach ($block->getUserDefinedAttributes() as $attribute):?>
        <?php $attributeContent = $block->getAttributeHtml($attribute);?>
        <?php $code = $attribute->getCode('allowed_for_retailer');?>

        //Checking if attribute is in allowed list or not.
        <?php if(in_array($code, $allowedAttributes)): ?>
            <?php if ($attributeContent): ?>
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $attributeContent ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endif;?>        
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. When I try it in local, it wasn't working but in the server its, working fine. Apart from this, I'm having one query that as of now, whatever attributes I'm creating via admin, they are displaying in all the customer groups but I don't want to display some customer attribute in some customer group. I have the code and put it in question. Can you please help me on that?

Comment: @Siva - Check my updated answer. It may help

Comment: Thanks. I'm mark this as answer

Comment: Glad to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to display Marital Status customer attribute in address of the customer you need to change it in  store->configurations->customers->configurations   and Address Templates

```
{{depend attribute_code}}Marital Status: {{var attribute_code}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: If you want to show customer attribute on frontend addresses shipping and billing address you need to update address templates in backend